# The ESTA website is down for a few days now. What are the alternatives?

Tags: usa, esta

The ESTA website has been down for days, and I wanted to check the validity of my ESTA. Trying to find an alternative I called the US Consulate in Athens (uselsess, they gave me the wrong phone number for CBP) and waiting at the CBP line 20 minutes though useless information (Seriously usability score is 0) until a very helpful lady there gave me the actual ESTA office phone number (at the moment of writing +12023443710) which I called at 09:30 EDT on Friday and was told that they cannot answer the phone right now as their normal office hours is 07:30 to 17:00 EST (I am sure they meant EDT/EST) Monday to Friday. Can anyone tell me what are the alternatives for and to obtaining an ESTA (and checking validity of one)? Is there some US gov service that actually answers? What will happen if I get there and the immigration officer tells me that my ESTA has expired?

UPDATE: The problem seems to be from my IP (and the http does not get redirected to https) and I managed to work around it by using a VPN to New York. I will hold out for an answer about alternatives as that is what the question was about.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hm, it's working for me (I'm in New York).  Are you using https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov (https)?  I wonder whether you are using http://esta.cbp.dhs.gov (http), which indeed does not work.

Comment: @phoog I added https screen shot. In any case normally (I know we are talking about a government here, but even they usually get it right) well configured websites will redirect to https from http

Comment: That's...strange!  Where on this planet (roughly) are you, as it works for me (Stateside) as well...

Comment: @UnrecognizedFallingObject I am in Athens... Wow I just VPNd to New York and it worked... Kind of defeats the purpose of running this site as only people outside the US will want to use it :-)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the availability checker with the HTTPS URL in the "I want to test" box?

Comment: @UnrecognizedFallingObject It seems there are two issues:
1. It seems that at least some IPs are blocked (at least mine) as I can actually connect using a VPN from New York.
2. http is not redirected to https so many of those tools are reporting the site as down.

Comment: @tarzan -- I agree that there's a misconfig on their end and that some IPs apparently aren't able to reach it as well (which is why I want the availability checker results when it's trying HTTPS -- that'd give us better data about who all can reach it)

Comment: @UnrecognizedFallingObject The URL was https://www.uptrends.com/tools/uptime however I am pretty sure it is only doing a HEAD or GET on port 80

Comment: It seems to be reaching the website properly from all locations when you put the HTTPS URL in...

Comment: @UnrecognizedFallingObject yes I saw that.. in that case probably only my IP is blocked for some reason (I hope none of my machines has caught anything..)

Comment: Try a traceroute to the site? I'm not sure what else to say here...

Comment: @tarzan i know, right? I first encountered this on I-94 site, which also requires you to type https into the browser.  Broken: http://i94.cbp.dhs.gov. Works: https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Having tested with, I think, the same availability checker you used to create your image, I am now very confident that your problem is that you're trying to reach

```
http://esta.cbp.dhs.gov
```

That, indeed, will not work.  Instead, use

```
https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov
```

You can add `https://` in the *I want to test* box, and the test will succeed.  Apparently, entering a bare domain name results in an HTTP connection attempt.  The ESTA server does not respond to these, but it does respond to HTTPS connections.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is half the solution to my problem but since the question is about alternatives, I think I'd better wait for an answer to that.

Comment: There are no alternatives, this is the only URL. Source: https://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/esta